# how to validate multiple TextBoxes with a MessageBox when clicked on "next"? visual studio(c# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, messagebox

I have a form that comprises 16 `jtextboxes` and 6 `comboBoxes`, and I want to validate all of them at once, or at least all `jtextboxes` at once and all `comboBoxes` at once. I have done that, but the problem is I use `MessageBox` as the validation to all of them and the `MessageBox` keeps on showing up after clicking on "Ok" or "Cancel".

Here is my code:

```
 private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 userform3 form3 = new userform3();
 var jtextboxes = new[] {
     jTextBox3, jTextBox4, jTextBox5, jTextBox6, jTextBox7, jTextBox8, jTextBox9, jTextBox10, jTextBox11, jTextBox12, jTextBox13, jTextBox14, jTextBox15, jTextBox16
 };
 var comboboxes = new[] {
     comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3, comboBox4, comboBox5, comboBox6
 };
 foreach(var jbox in jtextboxes) {
     foreach(var combo in comboboxes) {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jbox.TextValue) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(combo.Text)) {
             MessageBox.Show("some fields are empty");
         } else {
             form3.Show();
         }
     }
```

Is there a solution where the `MessageBox` shows up only once?

Comment: It seems that when you loop through you are going to show that MessageBox every time it encounters an empty jbox. An alternative would be to declare a bool ShowMessage = false and iterate through all of them. If any of them are found to be empty, set  the boolean to true in the loop. Then, when the loop is overwith, if(ShowMessage == true) display your MessageBox. And would you just return after the MessageBox? you would only display the form once the ShowMessage comes up false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a break statement (`break;`) to break out of the `foreach` loop once you use `MessageBox.Show()`.  Otherwise you can use a boolean that once the `MessageBox` is shown, it turns `true`.  Then only show the `MessageBox` when it's `false`.